# AddThis + Masonry cause overlap

Tags: javascript, addthis

I am running masonry layout on a set of divs, and I have added the addthis share button to each div. The layout was working before, but after adding the addthis script to the header all of the masonry is loading all overlapping its unreadable.

Is there something I can do so that when it loads it loads correctly? It seems that the addthis script is causing the issue. I have tried loading it in the header and footer, but each one cause the same issue.

Has anyone seen this issue? I know it's kind of specific to Masonry and AddThis together

`<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
                                                                                       <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-52a507e157ae2020"></script>`

There are no js errors in the console, so it's not a jQuery conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no idea what was causing this issue. I think it was my cache. Things are resolved.